# Is Google In-app Subscriptions available in Egypt?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I am going do develop new android app using google play services and I am asking Is Google In-app Subscriptions available in Egypt ? how it works for upgrading subscriptions pricing ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Egypt is listed as supporting Google Play Developer Registration and supporting Merchant Registration.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3539140?hl=en